# Redirect to current page value for input value in form

Tags: php, html, forms

In my html I currently have:

```
 <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="example.com" />
```

Is it possible to change the value to redirect to the current page (basically refreshing the page) without having to manually put the url in for each page?

Comment: Work not clear please describe

Comment: You can do:- `<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];?>" />`  Or `<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];?>" />`. But this will work only when page  extension will be `.php` not `.html`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you could add this function to your code. I use it in some of my application

create a function like :

```
function getPageUrlNoQuery()
{
    $pageUrl = ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    return $pageUrl;
}
```

include the function file, and call.

```
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="<?php echo getPageUrlNoQuery() ?>" />
```

Have edited, and i think this should work in most architecture as long as 
you can call the function, or class. whichever you use.

Comment: 1. He didn't want it in the `<form action>` attribute. 2. That may not work in every architecture, if I understand the way it works correctly.

Comment: @SourceOverflow yeah, u are right. Get i was sleepy when i posted that. intend to use the input tag.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in PHP you should know what page you are loading anyways and then put that value in. (I don't know your architecture, but either set a variable in your controller manually or if you don't use Controllers, then [simply extract the URL from the get request.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768793/get-the-full-url-in-php))

Alternatively you can use Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('YourLink').value = window.location.href;
```